# How to set dynamic boundaries/components for a simple game - JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to create a game in Java but I'm not sure how to set dynamic boundaries for it.

I have a default window size of 850 x 450 for the game.  I have a moving object that is controlled by the arrow keys.  I don't want the ball to move past the window size on each side of the window.  I know I can just check if x < 0 and x > 850 and check if y < 0 and y > 450.

However, I want the user to be able to expand or contract the window size to their preference.  This means the maximum and minimum window sizes will change.  So that means even though the window size is enlarged or decremented, the boundaries will still remain the same.  I want the boundaries to change when the window size is changed.  (Also, if the boundaries are going to be changed, I would need the ball to move in proportion to the boundaries that are moving.)  I did some research on Layout Managers but was still kind of lost on what to do with them. Any help?

Here are my classes:

```
package net.ihid.basicgame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Mikey on 1/23/2016.
 */
public class BasicGame {
    private static GamePanel gamePanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        startGame();
    }

    private static void startGame() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            gamePanel.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    package net.ihid.basicgame;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Mikey on 1/24/2016.
 */
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private JFrame frame;
    private MovingObject movingObject;

    public GamePanel() {
        movingObject = new MovingObject((float) 5.0);
        frame = new JFrame("Basic Game");

        frame.add(this);
        frame.setSize(850, 450);
        //frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addKeyListener(movingObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(movingObject.getX(), movingObject.getY(), 30, 30);
    }
}
```

---

```
package net.ihid.basicgame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

/**
 * Created by Mikey on 1/24/2016.
 */
public class MovingObject implements KeyListener {
    private int x, y;
    private float velocity;

    public MovingObject(float velocity) {
        x = 50;
        y = 50;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    private void checkOOB() {
        if(x < 0) x = 0;
        if(x > 850) x = 850;
        if(y < 0) y = 0;
        if(y > 450) y = 450;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
        float increment = 2*velocity;

        switch(keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                for(int i=0;i<increment;i++) {
                    y--;
                    checkOOB();
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                for(int i=0;i<increment;i++) {
                    y++;
                    checkOOB();
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                for(int i=0;i<increment;i++) {
                    x--;
                    checkOOB();
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                for(int i=0;i<increment;i++) {
                    x++;
                    checkOOB();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you can get the window size and check for it (getSize) or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html to listen for resize events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [componentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to get notified, if the component size changes. Another method is to use the getSize method each time, you check for field end.

(see also [componentAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentAdapter.html)).

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I decided I would not get so complicated with my approach and just set the resizeable property of the frame to false.  Thank you for the answer though, will keep that in mind when I work on more complicated games.